# Hudson failing to run post build script

Tags: hudson

My team and I have been working on some Spring Services and using Maven in Hudson to build the service then it has a Post build task of running a script which will deploy the project onto the development servers. One of these services will fail to run the deployment script on occasion. We have seen this before and don't know why this is happening.

The hudson logs are:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 43.818s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 23 10:42:27 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/238M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
channel stopped
Performing Post build task...
Could not match :executing deploy script  : False
Logical operation result is FALSE
Skipping script  : /home/oracle/bin/deployScript.sh
END OF POST BUILD TASK  : 0
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update; build not configured with trigger: custom-service #827
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 5):

It tells you why:

> Performing Post build task...
>   **Could not match** :executing deploy script  : False
>   Logical operation result is FALSE

Whatever text that it is looking for, in the console log, is not found.

Now as for *why* the text is not found: that's impossible to answer with the information provided so far. Provide:

- Exact configuration of your post-build criteria
- Full console output text for failing jobs
- Full console output text for successful jobs